# How do i check if the src attribute of an image is valid?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a meme generator, and when the user clicks a button, a meme should be generated, but if the image has not been selected, an empty image is created, so I want to create a sort of check to find out if the image has been set first.

Here's the code to select the image

```
function readURL(input) {
       if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
           var reader = new FileReader();

           reader.onload = function (e) {
               $('.blah')
                   .attr('src', e.target.result);
           };

           reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
       }
   }
```

after this i'm trying to create a check if the src attribute is set, but the code still runs and creates an empty image

```
function createMeme(){
  let make = $('.blah');
  let out = $('#img-out > img');
  if (make.src) {
    return "oijoijojioij";
  } else {
    html2canvas([document.getElementById('gen-img')], {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var imagedata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var imgdata = imagedata.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        //ajax call to save image inside folder
        $.ajax({
          url: 'save-image.php',
          data: {
            imgdata:imgdata
          },
          type: 'post',
          success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            out.attr('src', response);
          }
        })
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Even having a URL doesn't mean it's *valid*. You probably want to check if the image loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript Image class instead of FileReader()

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
   ...
};
img.onerror=function(){
   ...
};
img.src=URL;
```

Comment: okay, i guess i wasn't clear...that first function is just to set the src attribute of an image, to be same as that selected fot an input element